# What all topological properties are preserved under attaching a 2-cell?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $Y$ be a topological space.

Let $f:\mathbb{S}^1=\partial\mathbb{D}^2\rightarrow Y$ be a continuous map.

By attaching $2$-cell to $Y$ we mean the space $Y\bigsqcup  \mathbb{D}^2$ under the identification that $x\in \mathbb{S}^1$ is identified with its image $f(x)$ in $Y$.

Let us denote the quotient space $(Y\bigsqcup  \mathbb{D}^2)/\sim$ by $X$.

> Question : What all properties are preserved under attaching a $2$-cell?
>
> I am interested (but not limited to) Hausdorff, locally Hausdorff, regular, normal, compact, paracompact, contractible, locally contractible.

Comment: It is not necessary that you say all properties preserved under attaching. I would be thankful even if you say one in your answer... :)

Comment: Do you mean $S^0$ instead of $S^1$, and $Y\bigsqcup D^1$ instead of $Y\bigsqcup \partial D^1$?

Comment: I have problem with names.. Does it look ok now? @EricWofsey

Comment: Not all topological properties are preserved by attaching a 2-cell. For example, if $Y$ is a single point, then you get the 2-sphere, which is not contractible, does not have the same homotopy groups of a point, or homology groups, or cohomology groups. So, be careful ...

Comment: For example, compactness is trivial since your adjunction space is a quotient of a disjoint union of $Y$ compact and the 2-sphere compact. For Hausdoffness, and regularness, check out Hatcher's book, in the appendix about CW complexes.

Comment: @Laz I have seen that book... I was trying to collect all such properties... Not sure if that would be sensible.... :) :) Thanks,, I will read it once again..

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little broad. Some results are sketched in Laz's comments. This community wiki intends to collect known facts. The space $X$ is a special case of a *relative CW-complex*. The Appendix of [1] easily generalizes to give proofs of a lot of results. Section 1.8. of [2] contains a number of very general results on adjunction spaces.

Here are some answers based on these sources.

1) Separation axioms.

$T_1$ : Yes.

Hausdorff: Yes.

Regular: Yes.

Normal: Yes.

2) Compact.

Yes because you have a continuous surjection from the compact space $Y \bigsqcup  \mathbb{D}^2$ onto $X$.

3) Contractible.

No. Take $Y$ a single point space. Then $X$ is homeomorphioc to the $2$-sphere.

4) Locally contractible.

Yes. Modify the proof of Proposition A.4 in [1].

[1] Allen Hatcher, Algebraic topology

[2] Tammo tom Dieck, General Topology, https://www.uni-math.gwdg.de/tammo/GT01.pdf

Comment: Thanks... I will verify 4